# Fastest factorization process in java

Tags: java, algorithm, factorization

I am writing a program in java which works to calculate the sqrt of a given value up to 10^100
. For this, I know I have to use a BigInteger but the process I am dealing with is not so efficient as it takes a lot of time. What is the fastest process to factorize a number to deal with the program? What is the faster algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try any algorithm at all ? If yes, then can you post what you tried ?

Comment: Yeah... I tried general divide process

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  if(number/i==i) {printf("%d",i); break;}

Comment: What is `n` and `printf()` is **C** , not **Java**, though its immaterial !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844703/algorithm-to-find-the-factors-of-a-given-number-shortest-method

Comment: So you don't want a general factorization algorithm, just a square root?

Comment: Square root is needed but factorization algorithm is also a nice thing to deal with... Would help me to deal with a lot of uva problems :)

Comment: About my previous code, I wrote in C here, But you know you can implement it for a java biginteger

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope you realize that most input values won't have an exact integer answer for square root!  Are you sure you want to do this with BigInteger rather than BigDecimal?

You sure as heck don't want to iterate through each value up to n.  You need a way to improve your answers much more rapidly.  A simple way to do so is to make an initial guess for a value of the square root (I recommend n/2), and find its co-factor (n / guess).  If they're equal you're done, if they're not equal update your guess to be the average of the guess and its co-factor -- one of them will be greater than the actual square root, and the other will be smaller, so averaging will produce a value closer to the actual square root.  Lather, rinse, repeat.  If there isn't an exact square root, stop when the factor and the cofactor are within 1 of each other.

**Addendum:** Here it is in pseudo-code (actually Ruby, but that's pretty much the same thing):

```
def sqrt(n)
  guess = n / 2
  cofactor = 2
  loop do
    cofactor = n / guess
    break if (guess - cofactor).abs <= 1
    guess = (guess + cofactor) / 2
  end
  return [guess, cofactor].min
end
```

Translation to Java should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Great idea... Could you borrow me some implementations?? Whatever, the ans will be always Integer/BigInteger